# PHP/WHMCS: Creating accounts dynamically after payment is received?

Tags: php, whmcs

My website uses WHMCS. When a payment is made, the online bank service visits my website (a secret page in my website) that receives information (`POST`) telling my script that I've been paid. My script then uses the WMHCS API to create a new hosting account.

What methods must I use to protect this page from being improperly used by hackers?

The first thing I thought of is having a secret password variable (`POST`) that must be passed for the script to run the code. But I think that won't be enough.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use a seperate folder for that particular page.
Then you can use .htaccess within that folder,  to deny all requests from domains except the one you want.
In your .htaccess, something like below will work for your need.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .somedomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL, Settings > General and assign the ssl path once your cert is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should code a custom payment gateway for your whmcs instance. http://docs.whmcs.com/Gateway_Module_Developer_Docs

Answer (score 0):

If you go with paypal's ipn or any other payment notification, you can at least validate that it comes from a legal source, for example:

```
$remotehost = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); // turn remote ip into real host (paypal people configure dns properly)

$address = 'paypal.com'; // what to look for 

if(preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($address)."\b/i",$remotehost))
{
    // do ipn and it's ok
}
else
{
    // no ipn, because I cannot resolve that host to something paypal.com
}
```